# Android line path morphing animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-view

I basically have two lines, drawn by two paths on my canvas. Each one has only two points, one is supposed to remain standstill and the other one moves. I realized this simply by creating a Path and then call moveTo(x1, y1) and lineTo(x2, y2).

(x1, y1) never changes during time, I'd like to realize an animation when (x2, y2) is changing.

Here is the code I have for now:

```
public class ProgressDownload extends View {

private static final String LOG_TAG = ProgressDownload.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 10;
private static final int PADDING = 50;
private static final String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#EC5745";

private int mWidth, mHeight;
private int mProgress;
private Path mPathBlack, mPathWhite;
private Paint mPaintBlack, mPaintWhite;
private PathEffect mPathBlackEffect, mPathWhiteEffect;

public ProgressDownload(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR));
    setPadding(PADDING, 0, 50, PADDING);

    mPaintBlack = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintBlack.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaintBlack.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    mPaintBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    mPaintWhite = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintWhite.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaintWhite.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    mPaintWhite.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mPathBlackEffect = new CornerPathEffect(10);
    mPathWhiteEffect = new CornerPathEffect(10);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(mPathWhite != null && mPathBlack != null) {
        mPaintBlack.setPathEffect(mPathBlackEffect);
        mPaintWhite.setPathEffect(mPathWhiteEffect);

        canvas.drawPath(mPathBlack, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawPath(mPathWhite, mPaintWhite);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
    super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);
    mWidth = xNew - getPaddingRight();
    mHeight = yNew;
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("width and height measured are %d and %d", mWidth, mHeight));

    setPercentage(0);
}

private Path makePathBlack() {
    Path p =  new Path();

    p.moveTo(Math.max(getPaddingLeft(), mProgress*mWidth/100), mHeight/2 + calculatedeltaY());
    p.lineTo(mWidth, mHeight/2);

    return p;
}

private Path makePathWhite() {
    Path p = new Path();

    p.moveTo(getPaddingLeft(), mHeight / 2);
    p.lineTo(Math.max(getPaddingLeft(), mProgress*mWidth/100), mHeight/2 + calculatedeltaY());

    return p;
}

private int calculatedeltaY() {
    if(mProgress <= 50) {
        return  (mProgress * mWidth/6)/50;
    } else {
        return  ((100-mProgress) * mWidth/6)/50;
    }
}

public void setPercentage(int percentage) {
    if(percentage < 0 || percentage > 100)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("setPercentage not between 0 and 100");
    mProgress = percentage;
    mPathBlack = makePathBlack();
    mPathWhite = makePathWhite();
    invalidate();
}
}
```

I saw numerous possibilities on path animations, I guess I'd need something to update my current path to a new one.

setPercentage() here is updating both paths depending on the passed value. For now the transition between old and new paths is kinda "brutal". Any advices on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suddenly started to look into object animators. The solution is to use one that animates from my current percentage to the new percentage. The result is exactly what I wanted. Here is the updated view:

```
public class ProgressDownload extends View {

private static final String LOG_TAG = ProgressDownload.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 10;
private static final int PADDING = 50;
private static final long ANIMATION_DURATION = 1000;
private static final String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#EC5745";

private int mWidth, mHeight;
private int mProgress = 0;
private Path mPathBlack, mPathWhite;
private Paint mPaintBlack, mPaintWhite;
private PathEffect mPathBlackEffect, mPathWhiteEffect;

public ProgressDownload(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR));
    setPadding(PADDING, 0, 50, PADDING);

    mPaintBlack = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintBlack.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaintBlack.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    mPaintBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    mPaintWhite = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintWhite.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaintWhite.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    mPaintWhite.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mPathBlackEffect = new CornerPathEffect(10);
    mPathWhiteEffect = new CornerPathEffect(10);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(mPathWhite != null && mPathBlack != null) {
        mPaintBlack.setPathEffect(mPathBlackEffect);
        mPaintWhite.setPathEffect(mPathWhiteEffect);

        canvas.drawPath(mPathBlack, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawPath(mPathWhite, mPaintWhite);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
    super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);
    mWidth = xNew - getPaddingRight();
    mHeight = yNew;
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("width and height measured are %d and %d", mWidth, mHeight));

    setPercentage(mProgress);
}

private Path makePathBlack() {

    if(mPathBlack ==null) {
        mPathBlack = new Path();
    }

    Path p =  new Path();
    p.moveTo(Math.max(getPaddingLeft(), mProgress*mWidth/100), mHeight/2 + calculatedeltaY());
    p.lineTo(mWidth, mHeight/2);

    mPathBlack.set(p);

    return p;
}

private void makePathWhite() {

    if(mPathWhite ==null) {
        mPathWhite = new Path();
    }

    Path p = new Path();
    p.moveTo(getPaddingLeft(), mHeight / 2);
    p.lineTo(Math.max(getPaddingLeft(), mProgress * mWidth / 100), mHeight / 2 + calculatedeltaY());

    mPathWhite.set(p);
}

private int calculatedeltaY() {
    if(mProgress <= 50) {
        return  (mProgress * mWidth/6)/50;
    } else {
        return  ((100-mProgress) * mWidth/6)/50;
    }
}

public void setPercentage(int newProgress) {
    if(newProgress < 0 || newProgress > 100)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("setPercentage not between 0 and 100");

    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "progress", getProgress(), newProgress);
    anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.start();
}

public void setProgress(int progress) {
    mProgress = progress;
    makePathBlack();
    makePathWhite();
    invalidate();
}

public int getProgress() {
    return mProgress;
}
}
```